# Adding string [ ] value to XML message

Tags: php, xml, soap, formatting

I have an XML message that is created in PHP and then sent via CURL:

```
$xml_data ="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ord=\"http://medplus.com/orders\" xmlns:soapenc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">
";
$xml_data .="<soapenv:Header/>";
$xml_data .="<soapenv:Body>";
$xml_data .="<ord:getOrderDocuments soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">";
$xml_data .="<request xsi:type=\"java:OrderSupportServiceRequest\" xmlns:java=\"java:com.medplus.serviceHub.orders.webservice\">";
$xml_data .="<hl7Order xsi:type=\"xsd:base64Binary\">$HL7</hl7Order>";
$xml_data .="<orderSupportRequests xsi:type=\"java1:ArrayOfString\" soapenc:arrayType=\"xsd:string[]\" xmlns:java1=\"java:language_builtins.lang\">ABN</orderSupportRequests>";
$xml_data .="</request>";
$xml_data .="</ord:getOrderDocuments>";
$xml_data .="</soapenv:Body>";
$xml_data .="</soapenv:Envelope>";
```

I need to be able to "populate" the orderSupportRequests with 2 values "ABN" and "REQ"

How would I write that into my XML message above?

Thanks!

NCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `orderSupportRequests` as an array of strings.
You will have to wrap the children with another tag.

```
<orderSupportRequests 
     xsi:type="java1:ArrayOfString" 
     soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[2]"
     xmlns:java1="java:language_builtins.lang">

      <item xsi:type="xsd:string">ABN</item>
      <item xsi:type="xsd:string">REQ</item>

</orderSupportRequests>
```